# prevent javascript to encode url

Tags: javascript, url, urlencode, pushstate

I am trying to change url with `pushstate` in java script and my url doesn't have any space or bad character for url but java script encode it and add some character in it.
my code is:

```js
name= name.trim();
const nextState = { additionalInformation: name };
window.history.pushState(nextState, "", my_domain()+"/brands/" + name);
```

my url is:

```
http://localhost/brands/Brilliance
```

but it show as:

```
http://localhost/brands/Brilliance%E2%80%8C
```

Comment: From where this `name` is coming from? Maybe it has some symbols at the end that you do not trim? Like new line character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '%E2%80%8C' at the end of your URL is an invisible Unicode/ASCII character that you are likely copying when you have pasted in the URL, or maybe a package is causing it. In either case, here are two ways you can solve this:

---

1. 

You can paste your link into a hex editor and remove the invisible character manually before copy-pasting back into your code editor.

---

2. 

You can use this javascript solution to remove the characters:

```
function remove_non_ascii(str) {
  
  if ((str===null) || (str===''))
       return false;
 else
   str = str.toString();
  
  return str.replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/g, '');
}

console.log(remove_non_ascii('äÄçÇéÉêHello-WorldöÖÐþúÚ'));
```

Comment: it worked  for english character and tnx a lot. but when I call the method for persian character it return empty string.is there any way to protect persian character from encoding??

Answer (score 0):

The provided code has no reason to not work, but I have a suspicion that in fact `name` is malformed. If I get the `%E2%80%8C` suffix in the URL and run it trough `decodeURI`, I get an empty string. However, if I manually convert it to the string `\xe2\x80\x8c`, I get the following: `â\x80\x8C`. This most probably means corrupted data.

Answer (score 0):

Change your URL using **encodeURIComponent**

```
const nextState = encodeURIComponent('http://localhost/brands/Brilliance');
history.pushState({}, '', nextState);
```

This will change your url and the URL will not have any spaces and bad characters